# Extract numbers from a string using sed and regular expressions

Tags: regex, sed, integer

Another question for the sed experts.

I have a string representing an pathname that will have two numbers in it. An example is:

```
./pentaray_run2/Trace_220560.dat
```

I need to extract the second of these numbers - ie 220560

I have (with some help from the forums) been able to extract all the numbers together (ie 2220560) with:

```
sed "s/[^0-9]//g"
```

or extract only the first number with:

```
sed -r 's|^([^.]+).*$|\1|; s|^[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$|\1|'
```

But what I'm after is the second number!! Any help much appreciated.

PS the number I'm after is always the second number in the string.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

is this ok?

```
sed -r 's/.*_([0-9]*)\..*/\1/g'
```

with your example:

```
kent$   echo "./pentaray_run2/Trace_220560.dat"|sed -r 's/.*_([0-9]*)\..*/\1/g'
220560
```

Comment: Great works a treat. I guess _ in there means to look for numbers only after the underscore? In this instance I can always expect an underscore so this will work. Which actual bit of the expression does that is it .*_            Stackoverflow really is such a fantastic resource - I have been puzzling at this for hours.                    Out of interest do you think there is a way to use the \1 at the end - perhaps extract all numbers (contiguous digits) as substrings and ask for the second one. This could be useful to me and others in the future?

Answer (score 12):

You can extract the last numbers with this:

```
sed -e 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\+\)[^0-9]*$/\1/'
```

It is easier to think this backwards:

1. From the end of the string, match zero or more non-digit characters
2. Match (and capture) one or more digit characters
3. Match at least one non-digit character
4. Match all the characters to the start of the string

Part 3 of the match is where the "magic" happens, but it also limits your matches to have at least a non-digit before the number (ie. you can't match a string with only one number that is at the start of the string, although there is a simple workaround of inserting a non-digit to the start of the string).

The magic is to counter-act the left-to-right greediness of the `.*` (part 4). Without part 3, part 4 would consume all it can, which includes the numbers, but with it, matching makes sure that it stops in order to allow at least a non-digit followed by a digit to be consumed by parts 1 and 2, allowing the number to be captured.

Answer (score 9):

If `grep` is welcome :

```
$ echo './pentaray_run2/Trace_220560.dat' | grep -oP '\d+\D+\K\d+'
220560
```

And more portable with `Perl` with the same regex :

```
echo './pentaray_run2/Trace_220560.dat' | perl -lne 'print $& if /\d+\D+\K\d+/'
220560
```

I think the approach is cleaner & more robust than using `sed`

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/([^0-9]*([0-9]*)){2}.*/\2/' file
```

This extracts the second number:

```
sed -r 's/([^0-9]*([0-9]*)){1}.*/\2/' file
```

and this extracts the first.